# AMD Catalyst Overdrive worry

Tags: amd-catalyst

Last night, I explored catalyst and found this feature called Overdrive.

I checked the box and raised the following parameters

I raised the clock speeds by 200mhz for both gpu and memory.

I also set the fan speed from 40% to 60%.

I tested it with FFXIV ARR benchmark for a couple of minutes and an error message appeared, something like my gpu has failed. I closed the benchmark app right away and set my overdrive settings to default value.

My pc was still working right after that.

Here are my questions.

Did i just void my warranty after doing that?

Even though my pc is perfectly running until now. Did that left some permanent damage to my gpu?

Comment: It's not possible for is to tell you if there is damage or not

Comment: neither do I but maybe someone out there knows if increasing the parameters with that value would know the after effect of the short term increment.

Comment: We don't have enough information to even speculate.  Over-clocking would generate heat, heat kills electronics, this means it's entirely possible you damaged your hardware it's also possible you didn't

Comment: Run the benchmark with the default speeds, if it doesn't work you know it is duff, if it works you can be a little bit more confident that it is probably OK.

Answer (score 1):

It's a huge block of text, but you would have had to have agreed to the below terms and conditions to get to the Overdrive features in Catalyst.

You may have voided your warranty, or perhaps you haven't yet. The same goes with permanent damage. Your computer may have recovered from the error before any permanent damage was caused, or perhaps not.

> **WARNING** AMD and ATI processors are intended to be operated only within their associated specifications and factory settings. Operating your AMD or ATI processor outside of specification or in excess of factory settings, including but not limited to overclocking, may damage your processor and/or lead to other problems, including but not limited to, damage to your system components (including your motherboard and components thereon (e.g. memory)), system instabilities (e.g. data loss and corrupted images), shortened processor, system component and/or system life and in extreme cases, total system failure. AMD does not provide support or service for issues or damages related to use of an AMD or ATI processor outside of processor specifications or in excess of factory settings. You may also not receive support or service from your system manufacturer.
>
> **DAMAGES CAUSED BY USE OF YOUR AMD OR ATI PROCESSOR OUTSIDE OF SPECIFICATION OR IN EXCESS OF FACTORY SETTINGS ARE NOT COVERED UNDER YOUR AMD PRODUCT WARRANTY AND MAY NOT BE COVERED BY YOUR SYSTEM MANUFACTURER’S WARRANTY.**

Comment: This is so scary. I never knew that it would be that dangerous. Thank you for answering.